# Which properties would you study to evaluate spatial confinement of a molecule

Tags: solid-state-physics, configuration-interaction, materials-informatics

I'm modelling molecules confined within porous materials and I was wondering which molecular properties would you consider to access the confinement.

Í'm thinking about looking into long-range dispersion forces, the interaction energy, and the RMSD of MD runs. But I think other features might be more important.

Comment: How do you model the molecular confinement?

Comment: I'm converging molecules inside a molecular sized material, and of course that influences that properties. I have the same molecules confined in different sized and shaped pores and I would like to see how if some propertie is closely related to confinment

Comment: I think that confinement, per se, has nothing to do. The main issue there is that your molecule will interact (Coulombian, van der Waals, etc.) with the environment atoms.

Comment: @Camps in that case, molecules that are in a tighter spaces, i.e. more confined, should have higher coulombian and van der Waals interactions. Right? So that might be something to look at, as a way to describe the confinment of the molecule.

Comment: Sure, but, again: how do you define a confinement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vibrational properties of the molecule should change under confinement. You could compute IR spectra or more simply vibrational spectra of the molecule to probe this. The benefit of this is that you could compare this directly with experiments.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. But anyway do you expect any trend from being more or less confined in terms on the extent of vibrations?

Comment: I think it would be very system dependent, I’m not sure.

Comment: How do you model the molecular confinement?

Answer (score 3):

The KS spectrum should change: the more confined is the molecule, the larger should be the HOMO-LUMO gap.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. May I ask what KS means?

Comment: Kohn-Sham, sorry.